# Ubuntu NFS - /var/nfs requires sudo

Tags: server, permissions, nfs

So I have setup a NFS client and server both running on Ubuntu server. The server is 14.04 and the client is 14.10. Not that it is related, but these are virtual servers on digitalocean.

I have created a directory /var/nfs and I set the permissions to be nobody:nogroup.

```
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /var/nfs
```

I am able to mount the nfs no problem and they can sync up, but the problem is I need to use sudo to put anything in /var/nfs on the server and on the client I also need to use sudo to access anything

Since I set the permissions of the folder to be nobody:nogroup shouldn't it allow me to put things in there without sudo?

I am not sure of the command to check owner and group, but I did find

```
 stat -c '%U' /var/nfs
```

reports back nobdy, so im sure the ownership took effect.

Edit: I should say I followed a guide to set this up and they suggested nobody:nogroup permissions are /var/nfs. Should I just change it to that of my home user:group since I am pretty much only account and person that uses it?

Comment: "Since I set the permissions of the folder to be nobody:nogroup shouldn't it allow me to put things in there without sudo?" Why? Are you `nobody` or in `nogroup`?

Comment: No, the guide suggested I set it to that so I thought that it had either something to do with how nfs handles things, or it allowed for anyone to use the /var/nfs folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting ownership to `nobody:nogroup` does exactly that and nothing more. I see no reason to do so, since `nobody` can't login, and `nogroup` has no other members, usually. As a security measure, I don't think it has any benefits over `root:root`.

> Should I just change it to that of my user:group?

That depends. The ownership is determined by the UID and the GID, so check the values of `id -u` and `id -g` on both systems. If they agree, yes, that's the best option. If not, then I suggest setting the only other known values: `root:root`.

Comment: Perfect! The UID and the GID's matched up so I just changed ownership over to me. I am a little confused what to do if I want to give my wife access, but nothing a little reading can't solve. Now that I think of it, maybe even just create a group and chown+chmod directory for group read/write